# What would be a proper javascript code expression to this python code

Tags: javascript, python, random, converters

How can I convert this code to javascript? I've tried different compilers, but none of them worked for me, guess I just couldn't figure out how to use them

```
import random
randDuration = random.randint(1000, 2000)/1000
```

It's a code generating random numbers between 1 and 2 with a thousandth fraction.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried randDuration = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2.001 - 1.000) ) + 1.000; , but both answers work, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 * 1000 - 1 * 1000) + 1 * 1000) / (1*1000);

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` generate random **float number** between 0 and 1, then add 1, and the number will be from 1 to 2, and finally convert to deciaml 3 using toFixed().

`(Math.random()+1).toFixed(3)`

Since to fix convert it to string, you can convert it back using `Number()` method e.g. `Number(Math.random()+1).toFixed(3))`